# Show value of $\int_0^{\infty}ae^{-a\cdot x^2}dx$ is independent on $a$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, parametric

I have to prove that the value of $$\int_0^{\infty}ae^{-ax^2}dx$$ does not depend on $a>0$.
I have thought to show the convergence of the integral but then how can I conclude this resul does not depend on $a$?

Comment: Use the good ol' Taylor series.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your problem statement.

Comment: I do not think the statement is true. After all, if we substitute $x=u/\sqrt a$, we get
$$
\int_0^\infty a\exp(-ax^2)dx=\sqrt a\int_0^\infty \exp(-u^2)du,
$$
which is proportional with $\sqrt a$.

Comment: @kimchilover yeah thanks I have solved the typo

Comment: @MostafaAyaz but the RHS how can help me to conclude the value does not depend on a?

Comment: Perhaps try to prove that $f'(a) = 0$ with $f(a) : = \int_0^{\infty}1/ae^{-(x/a)^2}dx$ ?

Comment: @KamalSaleh the taylor series of $e^{-(x/a)^2}$?

Comment: @jin No, the taylor series of the integrand.

Comment: As stated, you will *not* be able to prove this. If you could, then the answer obtained [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B2*Exp%5B-2Square%5Bx%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D-Integrate%5B1*Exp%5B-1Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) would be $0.$

Comment: It *is* possible if the integrand is $ae^{-(ax)^2},$ though.

Answer (score 4):

In your integral make the substitution $y=\frac{x}{a}$.
This gives $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$$
a definite integral which does not involve $a$.

NOTE
This answer was for the question as originally set. The OP has now changed the question into a form where the result is incorrect.

Comment: Well but then I should turn back to x to find the primitive, and $a$ appears again

Comment: You obtain the same integral whatever $a$ is and that's what being independent of $a$ means.

Comment: But I can't use the fact I know $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}=\sqrt{\pi}/2$

Comment: You aren't using that fact .

Comment: All you need is that it is a definite integral that does not involve $a$.

Comment: And how can I say: "I obtain the same integral whatever is a"?

Comment: Say "and this does not involve $a$".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146224/discussion-between-jin-and-user1172706).

Comment: With the substitution $y=x/a$, you get to $\int_0^\infty a^2\exp(-a^3y^2)dy$, not $\int_0^\infty \exp(-y^2)dy$.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz The integral should be $\int\limits_0^{\infty} a\, e^{-(a\, x)^2} \, dx$ in which case the substitution $x=y/a$ works.